# Why Am I Receiving Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sigabrt

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

The error is on the previous line of code. I think the error has something to do with the following code in my GameScene.swift. I typed the following code for my game logic.

In the game, four triangles comprise a square. One of four nodes falls from the top of the screen, and if it hits the correct side of the square (you can rotate the square by clicking on the screen), another node is re-spawned. The following code does not run correctly, and I get the error message Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.

```
import SpriteKit


class GameScene: SKScene {


let basicTop = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "basic top");
let basicBottom = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "basic bottom");
let basicLeft = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "basic left");
let basicRight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "basic right");
let brickTop = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Top Side");
let brickBottom = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bottom Side");
let brickLeft = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Left Side");
let brickRight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Right Side copy 2");

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
layoutScene()

}



func layoutScene() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 10/255, green: 75/255, blue: 150/255, alpha: 1.0)

    spawnBrick()
    spawnBasicTop()
    spawnBasicBottom()
    spawnBasicLeft()
    spawnBasicRight()
    backgroundScene()
    setupPhysics()

}

func setupPhysics() {
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -0.1)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
}

func spawnBrick()  {
    let randomFunc = [self.spawnbrickTop, self.spawnbrickBottom, self.spawnbrickLeft, self.spawnbrickRight]
    let randomResult = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomFunc.count)))
    randomFunc[randomResult]()
}



func spawnbrickTop() {

    brickTop.size = CGSize(width: 224, height: 93)
    brickTop.name = "BrickTop"
    brickTop.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY)
    brickTop.zPosition = 0
    //physics stuff begins here
    brickTop.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: brickTop.size)
    brickTop.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.brickTopCategory
    brickTop.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicTopCategory
    brickTop.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicBottomCategory
    brickTop.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicLeftCategory
    brickTop.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicRightCategory
    brickTop.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.none
     //bye bye physics
    self.addChild(brickTop)

}

func spawnbrickBottom() {

    brickBottom.size = CGSize(width: 230, height: 101)
    brickBottom.name = "BrickBottom"
    brickBottom.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY)
    brickBottom.zPosition = 0
    //physics stuff begins here
    brickBottom.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: brickBottom.size)
    brickBottom.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.brickBottomCategory
    brickBottom.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicTopCategory
    brickBottom.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicBottomCategory
    brickBottom.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicLeftCategory
    brickBottom.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicRightCategory
    brickBottom.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.none
     //bye bye physics
    self.addChild(brickBottom)
}

func spawnbrickLeft() {

    brickLeft.size = CGSize(width: 210, height: 70)
    brickLeft.name = "BrickLeft"
    brickLeft.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY)
    brickLeft.zPosition = 0
    //physics stuff begins here
    brickLeft.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: brickLeft.size)
    brickLeft.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.brickLeftCategory
    brickLeft.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicTopCategory
    brickLeft.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicBottomCategory
    brickLeft.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicLeftCategory
    brickLeft.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicRightCategory
    brickLeft.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.none
     //bye bye physics
    self.addChild(brickLeft)

}


func spawnbrickRight() {

    brickRight.size = CGSize(width: 190, height: 84)
    brickRight.name = "BrickRight"
    brickRight.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY)
    brickRight.zPosition = 0
    //physics stuff begins here
    brickRight.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: brickRight.size)
    brickRight.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.brickRightCategory
    brickRight.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicTopCategory
    brickRight.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicBottomCategory
    brickRight.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicLeftCategory
    brickRight.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicRightCategory
    brickRight.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.none
     //bye bye physics
    self.addChild(brickRight)

}





func turnBasicTop() {
    basicTop.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi/2, duration: 0.25))
}

func turnBasicBottom() {
    basicBottom.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi/2, duration: 0.25))
}

func turnBasicLeft() {
    basicLeft.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi/2, duration: 0.25))
}

func turnBasicRight() {
    basicRight.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi/2, duration: 0.25))
}

func gameOver() {
    print("Game Over!")
}

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        turnBasicTop()
        turnBasicBottom()
        turnBasicLeft()
        turnBasicRight()

    }


func spawnBasicTop() {

    basicTop.size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)
    basicTop.position = CGPoint(x: 230, y: 200)
    basicTop.zPosition = 1


    //physics stuff begins here
    basicTop.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: basicTop.size)
    basicTop.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicTopCategory
    basicTop.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    basicTop.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    //bye bye physics


    addChild(basicTop)
}

func spawnBasicBottom() {

    basicBottom.size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)
    basicBottom.position = CGPoint(x: 230, y: 200)
    basicBottom.zPosition = 1

    //physics stuff begins here
    basicBottom.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: basicBottom.size)
    basicBottom.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicBottomCategory
    basicBottom.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    //bye bye physics


    addChild(basicBottom)
}
func spawnBasicLeft() {

    basicLeft.size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)
    basicLeft.position = CGPoint(x: 230, y: 200)
    basicLeft.zPosition = 1

    //physics stuff begins here
    basicLeft.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: basicLeft.size)
    basicLeft.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicLeftCategory
    basicLeft.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    //bye bye physics


    addChild(basicLeft)
}

func spawnBasicRight() {

    basicRight.size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)
    basicRight.position = CGPoint(x: 230, y: 200)
    basicRight.zPosition = 1

    //physics stuff begins here
    basicRight.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: basicRight.size)
    basicRight.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicRightCategory
    basicRight.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    //bye bye physics


    addChild(basicRight)
}


func backgroundScene() {
let constructionSite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background Image")
    constructionSite.size = frame.size
    constructionSite.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    constructionSite.zPosition = -1
    addChild(constructionSite)
}
}


extension GameScene: SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    //01
    //10
    //11
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask |
        contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    if contactMask == PhysicsCategories.brickTopCategory |
        (PhysicsCategories.basicTopCategory) {
        if let brickTop = contact.bodyA.node?.name == "BrickTop" ?
            contact.bodyA.node as? SKSpriteNode : contact.bodyB.node as?
            SKSpriteNode {
            if brickTop == basicTop {
                print("Correct!")
                brickTop.run(SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.15), completion: {
                    brickTop.removeFromParent()
                    self.spawnBrick()
                })
            }
            else if contactMask == PhysicsCategories.brickBottomCategory |
            (PhysicsCategories.basicBottomCategory) {
            if let brickBottom = contact.bodyA.node?.name == "BrickBottom" ?
                contact.bodyA.node as? SKSpriteNode : contact.bodyB.node as?
                SKSpriteNode {
                if brickBottom == basicBottom {
                    print("Correct!")
                    brickBottom.run(SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.15), completion: {
                        brickBottom.removeFromParent()
                        self.spawnBrick()
                    })
                }
            else if contactMask == PhysicsCategories.brickLeftCategory |
                           (PhysicsCategories.basicBottomCategory) {
                           if let brickLeft = contact.bodyA.node?.name == "BrickLeft" ?
                               contact.bodyA.node as? SKSpriteNode : contact.bodyB.node as?
                               SKSpriteNode {
                               if brickLeft == basicLeft {
                                   print("Correct!")
                                   brickLeft.run(SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.15), completion: {
                                       brickLeft.removeFromParent()
                                    self.spawnBrick()
                                   })
                               }
           else if contactMask == PhysicsCategories.brickRightCategory |
                          (PhysicsCategories.basicRightCategory) {
                          if let brickRight = contact.bodyA.node?.name == "BrickRight" ?
                              contact.bodyA.node as? SKSpriteNode : contact.bodyB.node as?
                              SKSpriteNode {
                              if brickRight == basicRight {
                                  print("Correct!")
                                  brickRight.run(SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.15), completion: {
                                      brickRight.removeFromParent()
                                    self.spawnBrick()
                                  })
                              }
            else {
                gameOver()
            }


                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
              }
            }
}
}



}
}
```

The following is printed in the console when the error happens:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already 
has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'BrickLeft' texture:[<SKTexture> 'Left 
Side' (254 x 165)] position:{207, 896} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{210, 70} 
anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c710bc +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   SpriteKit                           0x00007fff2be8cba1 -[SKNode insertChild:atIndex:] + 157
    4   SpriteKit                           0x00007fff2be8cae1 -[SKNode addChild:] + 68
    5   Brick Switch                        0x000000010ee913b0 $s12Brick_Switch9GameSceneC14spawnbrickLeftyyF + 2816
    6   Brick Switch                        0x000000010ee97e7c $sTA.40 + 28
    7   Brick Switch                        0x000000010ee8ebcc $sIeg_ytIegr_TR + 12
    8   Brick Switch                        0x000000010ee8edc1 $sIeg_ytIegr_TRTA.8 + 17
    9   Brick Switch                        0x000000010ee8eaad $s12Brick_Switch9GameSceneC05spawnA0yyF + 781
    10  Brick Switch                        0x000000010ee96ba5 $s12Brick_Switch9GameSceneC8didBeginyySo16SKPhysicsContactCFyycfU2_ + 85
    11  Brick Switch                        0x000000010ee96a7d $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 45
    12  SpriteKit                           0x00007fff2be2483e _ZN9SKCAction25didFinishWithTargetAtTimeEP7SKCNoded + 44
    13  SpriteKit                           0x00007fff2be26090 _ZN7SKCFade27cpp_updateWithTargetForTimeEP7SKCNoded + 184
    14  SpriteKit                           0x00007fff2be3a49b _ZN7SKCNode6updateEdf + 221
    15  SpriteKit                           0x00007fff2be3a560 _ZN7SKCNode6updateEdf + 418
    16  SpriteKit                           0x00007fff2be51e2b -[SKScene _update:] + 613
    17  SpriteKit                           0x00007fff2be726c9 -[SKView _update:] + 953
    18  SpriteKit                           0x00007fff2be6ed91 __51-[SKView _vsyncRenderForTime:preRender:postRender:]_block_invoke.323 + 281
    19  SpriteKit                           0x00007fff2be6e180 -[SKView _vsyncRenderForTime:preRender:postRender:] + 527
    20  SpriteKit                           0x00007fff2be6fdb8 __29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 203
    21  SpriteKit                           0x00007fff2beb3992 -[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 301
    22  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2afeb266 _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 640
    23  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b0c3e03 _ZL22display_timer_callbackP12__CFMachPortPvlS1_ + 299
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b9503d __CFMachPortPerform + 157
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd4bc9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd4228 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 472
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bced64 __CFRunLoopRun + 2516
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bce066 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff384c0bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
    30  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48092d4d UIApplicationMain + 1621
    31  Brick Switch                        0x000000010ee99e2b main + 75
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5227ec25 start + 1
    33  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

This is the Settings file:

```
enum PhysicsCategories {
    static let none: UInt32 = 0
    static let brickCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1//01
    static let brickTopCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2//01
     static let brickBottomCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 3//01
    static let brickLeftCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 4//01
    static let brickRightCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 5//01
    static let  basicTopCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 6 //10; shifts all bits to the left
    static let  basicBottomCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 7 //10; shifts all bits to the left
    static let  basicLeftCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 8 //10; shifts all bits to the left
    static let  basicRightCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 9 //10; shifts all bits to the left
}
```

Comment: which line produces the error? Have you tried addind a `Exception Breakpoint`?

Comment: There should be some output in the debug window.

Comment: The error is on the "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {" line.

Comment: That line is just a catch-all because something in the program recognized a severe logic error and called for an abort. As @AndreasOetjen said, there's probably some message in the debug output console in Xcode. A typical SpriteKit issue that would cause an abort is something like trying to `addChild` with a node that already has a parent.

Comment: @bg2b I am editing the question to say what the console says when the app has the bug

Comment: It tells you exactly the problem: "Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: name:'BottomBrick' texture:[ 'Bottom Side' (234 x 138)] position:{207, 896} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{230, 101} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00"

Comment: @bg2b So what do I need to change in my code in order to re-spawn a brick in my game

Comment: I can't say without seeing the program, but whatever you're doing in spawning a brick is trying to add a node to the scene while it's already there. Maybe set a breakpoint in the debugger where you do the spawn so you can examine the program state and figure out why that's happening.

Comment: @bg2b I am going to edit the question to show all the code. Also, to add for clarification, when my brick hits the square, instead of removing the brick, the game removes three of the triangles that make up the square.

Comment: Not sure about your contact handling since the logic is very convoluted, but the contact bit masks are almost certainly wrong. The sequences of four lines of the form `brickRight.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ...` are all equivalent to just the last line alone. You presumably meant to have the bitwise OR of the categories.

Comment: @bg2b Any suggestions on what to change?

Comment: @bg2b I have made some changes in the Settings.swift file. I am putting what it looks like above.Upon making these changes, the app runs without any errors, but there is no logic. When the brick passes through the square at the bottom, nothing happens. Nothing re-spawns or de-spawns.

Comment: You should always go into your debugger and search for the word 'reason' That would then help you find the exact error.

Comment: @Honey Sorry, I should have changed the title. As I said earlier in the comments, I am not receiving an error anymore, but I don’t have anymore game logic. I am going to edit the settings file to see if that makes anything change.

Comment: I think the problem with the logic might be that the brick nodes  are contacting all triangles nodes that make up the square. I was thinking that the brick was only hitting the top section of the square, but it is actually falling through and hitting all parts of the square.

Answer (score 0):

Try avoid using global variables whenever possible.  This is definitely a case where you want to create multiple objects.

<s>let brickTop = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Top Side");</s>
<s>let brickBottom = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bottom Side");</s>
<s>let brickLeft = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Left Side");</s>
<s>let brickRight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Right Side copy 2");</s>

```
func spawnbrickTop() {
    let brickTop = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Top Side");

    brickTop.size = CGSize(width: 224, height: 93)
    brickTop.name = "BrickTop"
    brickTop.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY)
    brickTop.zPosition = 0
    //physics stuff begins here
    brickTop.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: brickTop.size)
    brickTop.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.brickTopCategory
    brickTop.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicTopCategory
    brickTop.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicBottomCategory
    brickTop.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicLeftCategory
    brickTop.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicRightCategory
    brickTop.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.none
     //bye bye physics
    self.addChild(brickTop)

}

func spawnbrickBottom() {
    let brickBottom = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bottom Side");

    brickBottom.size = CGSize(width: 230, height: 101)
    brickBottom.name = "BrickBottom"
    brickBottom.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY)
    brickBottom.zPosition = 0
    //physics stuff begins here
    brickBottom.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: brickBottom.size)
    brickBottom.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.brickBottomCategory
    brickBottom.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicTopCategory
    brickBottom.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicBottomCategory
    brickBottom.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicLeftCategory
    brickBottom.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicRightCategory
    brickBottom.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.none
     //bye bye physics
    self.addChild(brickBottom)
}

func spawnbrickLeft() {
    let brickLeft = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Left Side");

    brickLeft.size = CGSize(width: 210, height: 70)
    brickLeft.name = "BrickLeft"
    brickLeft.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY)
    brickLeft.zPosition = 0
    //physics stuff begins here
    brickLeft.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: brickLeft.size)
    brickLeft.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.brickLeftCategory
    brickLeft.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicTopCategory
    brickLeft.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicBottomCategory
    brickLeft.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicLeftCategory
    brickLeft.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicRightCategory
    brickLeft.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.none
     //bye bye physics
    self.addChild(brickLeft)

}


func spawnbrickRight() {

    let brickRight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Right Side copy 2");

    brickRight.size = CGSize(width: 190, height: 84)
    brickRight.name = "BrickRight"
    brickRight.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY)
    brickRight.zPosition = 0
    //physics stuff begins here
    brickRight.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: brickRight.size)
    brickRight.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.brickRightCategory
    brickRight.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicTopCategory
    brickRight.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicBottomCategory
    brickRight.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicLeftCategory
    brickRight.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.basicRightCategory
    brickRight.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.none
     //bye bye physics
    self.addChild(brickRight)

}
```

Comment: I will definitely change it to that. Thanks for the suggestion!